# Correct way of referencing external header/source files with Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk

i'm making a 3D app that needs the GLM lib. My NDK directory contains the GLM lib source code so I try to link it by using :

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/libs
```

I wanted to do :

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += Android/SDK/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/libs
```

I found on the Android doc that LOCAL_C_INCLUDES was relative to the NDK root.
[link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html#mdv)

The documentation is a bit confusing, it mentions the root directory of the NDK but gives an example with the local directory of the app (where your native modules go).

My questions are :

- Is there a correct way to reference external files (cpp/hpp) from my
  application using Android.mk
- Do I have to use all the ../ to keep
  relative pathing ?
- Do I have to copy all the GLM files into a libs
  folder in my application ?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The NDK test for the validation layers shows how to import them: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ccb50936470af0c6ccf35bc463a0723b637fd1cd/tests/build/vulkan_layers/jni/Android.mk#12

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := vulkan
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := instance.cpp
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11 -DVK_PROTOTYPES
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lvulkan
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := shaderc glslang
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

$(call import-module,third_party/shaderc)
$(call import-module,third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jni)
```

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work. Can you paste the code instead?

Comment: Sorry about that. It worked when I originally posted it but the test moved. I've updated the answer with a link to a specific revision so that doesn't happen again in the future.